# Npgsql: Discrepency with Guids between Database.Migrate and Database.EnsureCreated

Tags: .net-core, npgsql, .net-standard-2.0

In a netstandard20 project, I'm using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.0 and I'm having an issue using `Guid` as the type for my primary keys. If I use `Database.EnsureCreated()` to create the schema, the primary key columns get created with data type `uuid`. With everything the same except changing it to use `Database.Migrate()` creates all the primary key columns with data type `text` and then I get exception: `Npgsql.PostgresException : 42883: operator does not exist: text = uuid` when I try to perform any operations.

There is a single migration in my project to create the initial database. In that migration and also in the "context model snapshot" that are auto-generated, the primary key columns are all defined as `Guid`.

I need to both use the `Database.Migrate()` method to create the database and also have it create the `Guid` primary key columns as `uuid`. How can I make sure it creates the columns correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this issue and response](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/566#issuecomment-410330017) after posting my question. It led me to the correct answer which was that when I created the migration I was using sqlite. I needed to blow away the migration created against that data provider and regenerate it.